# How do I make a folder from a string containing an apostrophe using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unix, escaping, text-processing, gsub

I have the following string:

```
"Gender and Women's Studies"
```

I am trying to convert it to:

```
"Gender\ and\ Women\'s\ Studies"
```

so that I can make a valid Unix folder with that string.

How would I go about this in Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use [`Dir.mkdir("Gender and Women's Studies")`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir).

There's no need to escape anything if you let Ruby do the work. If you need to use the file from the command-line then you'd need to deal with escaping.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was hoping there was a nice ruby way to do this!

Comment: One last doubt, what if I want to make this directory under another directory... Currently I'm doing something like `cd Courses && mkdir GWS` .... how do I do the equivalent with the Dir syntax? Thanks!

Comment: nvm. I figured it out.. had to use Dir.chdir and make the directory within that do..end statement like so: `Dir.chdir("newdir") do Dir.mkdir("Something") end`

Comment: `Dir.chdir('newdir') && Dir.mkdir('something')` would be how I'd do it. Using `do` probably pops the `chdir` as soon as the `mkdir` finishes, but I haven't checked the docs to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing that if you can. Although Unix can work with such directories (folder is what Windows calls them), many programs, scripts and utilities are written and tested as if directory (and file) names come without punctuation including spaces, and can become difficult to use.

I manipulate the file-system with such programs and scripts and have learnt that names of [a-zA-Z0-9_], (without the dash '-'), give the least problems.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. I'll take this into account if I'm working with Windows. Right now, Im working under unix only.. so this is not that much of an issue.

Comment: @sambehera: Hi, I meant that I do this for Unix systems - not Windows.